# GWT 2.1 CellTable Shows Only Loading Bar

Tags: gwt

Following both the example from the GWT Showcase and the example found at [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#celltable), I implemented a CellTable.  The CellTable displays the first 15 results but subsequent pages only displays the loading bar.  Attempting to return to the first 15 results shows only the loading bar as well.  No errors in the JavaScript console or within the GWT developer console are raised.

Any help or insight that anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Further, I tried the following and it too suffered from the same thing happening:

```
    List<String> stringsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for( int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
        stringsList.add("" + i);
    }

    CellTable<String> cellTable = new CellTable();

    TextColumn<String> nameColumn = new TextColumn<String>(){
        @Override
        public String getValue(String string){
            return string;
        }
    };

    SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
    SimplePager pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 0, true);
    pager.setDisplay(cellTable);

    cellTable.addColumn(nameColumn, "App Name");
    cellTable.setRowCount(stringsList.size(), true);
    cellTable.setRowData(0, stringsList);
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(cellTable);
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(pager);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't use a DataProvider and setList to fill the Table? Somewhere I read that this is the recommended approach and setRowData shouldn't be used (because it can cause some weird behaviour)

Comment: I went and implemented a dataProvider like you suggested and that got everything working.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a data provider to push data into the cell table. Add the next code and it should work.

```
ListDataProvider dataProvider = new ListDataProvider();
dataProvider.setList(stringsList );  
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there's some problem with setVisibleRange or a similar method.  I get this a lot when a list backing the data provider doesn't have enough values, or something.  I recommend you trace your program to the point at which you're changing the visible range and check all the values that are going into your methods there.

Comment: I edited my initial post to include a code snippet that I tried that produces the same results as I have been seeing through my more complicated implementation.